# What is the color space produced by MSS sct.grab()?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-mss

*Python 3.10,
opencv-python==4.5.4.60*

I'm having a hard time understanding the color format of screenshots taken by MSS.

Here is the portion of my screen that I am screenshotting (with correct/expected colors, taken manually):

[image]

Here is the screenshot code I'm working with:

```
with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = rect
    res = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))[:, :, :3] # remove alpha
```

When I use `cv2.imsave()` or `cv2.imshow()`, the screenshot looks as expected. If I attempt to create masks on this image based on [R, G, B] colors, it produces opposite results, implying that the default color space of MSS Screenshots is BGRA.

If I do the following:

```
res = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It produces this:

[image]

However, *then* I am able to perform RGB masking properly.

**I may have just answered my own question, but is it correct to say that MSS Screenshots are in BGRA format, and OpenCV *expects* BGR format - which would explain why RGB images have reversed colors when using `cv2.imshow()` and `cv2.imsave()`?**

Comment: Yes, you answered your own question, OpenCV works in BGR[A] (at least the input/output/visualization parts, much of the processing doesn't care, it's just a bunch of numbers) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, MSS uses BGRA:

- https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=BGRA#mss.tools.mss.base.ScreenShot.__array_interface__
- https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/blob/v7.0.1/mss/screenshot.py#L30
- https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/blob/v7.0.1/mss/screenshot.py#L46-L47

You can even find some tips for the conversion: https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#bgra-to-rgb

Indeed, I would be glad to enhance the documentation if you find something better :)

Answer (score 0):

if you need it, here you go:

```
screenshot = sct.grab(bbox)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', screenshot.size, screenshot.bgra, 'raw', 'BGRX')
arr = np.array(img)
res = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
out.write(res)
```